# How to find those rows which don't exist in another CSV file using python 3.7.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a file ua.csv which has 2 rows and another file pr.csv which has 4 rows. I would like to know what are those rows which are present in pr.csv and ua.csv doesn't. Need to have count of extra rows present in pr.csv in the output.

```
ua.csv
```

```
Name|Address|City|Country|Pincode
Jim Smith|123 Any Street|Boston|US|02134 
Jane Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130
```

```
pr.csv
```

```
Name|Address|City|Country|Pincode
Jim Smith|123 Any Street|Boston|US|02134 
Smoet|coffee shop|finland|Europe|3453335
Jane Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130 
Jack|long street|malasiya|Asia|585858
```

Below is the expected output:

```
pr.csv has 2 rows extra

Name|Address|City|Country|Pincode
Smoet|coffee shop|finland|Europe|3453335
Jack|long street|malasiya|Asia|585858
```

Comment: What do you mean by `but ua.csv doesn't have along with count`?

Comment: can you use pandas for the same?

Comment: @LinFelix - rephrased my question

Comment: One approach is to create two sets of strings where the first set as all the lines from the first CSV file and the second set has all the strings from the second CSV file. Then take the set difference between the two sets.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the `set` datastructure:

```py
ua_set = set()
pr_set = set()

# Code to populate the sets reading the csv files (use the `add` method of sets)
...

# Find the difference
diff = pr_set.difference(ua_set)

print(f"pr.csv has {len(diff)} rows extra")

# It would be better to not hardcode the name of the columns in the output 
# but getting the info depends on the package you use to read csv files
print("Name|Address|City|Country|Pincode")  

for row in diff:
    print(row)
```

A better solution using the `pandas` module:

```py
import pandas as pd

df_ua = pd.read_csv("ua.scv") # Must modify path to ua.csv
df_pr = pd.read_csv("pr.csv") # Must modify path to pr.csv

df_diff = df_pr.merge(df_ua, how="outer", indicator=True).loc[lambda x: x["_merge"] == "left_only"].drop("_merge", axis=1)

print(f"pr.csv has {len(df_diff)} rows extra")

print(df_diff)
```

Comment: It is working but not completely. Output is even giving that row which is present but in some other order like below line is present at row2 in ua.csv and same is present at row 3. output is coming like this


 ```
pr.csv has 3 rows extra
Name|Address|City|Country|Pincode
Jane Lee|248 Another St.|Boston|US|02130

Jack|long street|malasiya|Asia|585858
Smoet|coffee shop|finland|Europe|3453335
```

Comment: The `set` data structure is not ordered, which means that the order in which elements are placed in the set doesn't matter so I guess you made a mistake when populating the sets. When you read the csv file, maybe an index is added to each rows which would make 2nd row in ua.csv and 3rd row in pr.csv have different string representations

Comment: It gave me this error pr.csv has 0 rows extra
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name|Address|City|Country|Pincode, _merge]
Index: []

Comment: @Enigmaderockz, change `right_only` to `left_only`. Also drop the newly created `_merge` column. The line should look like: `df_diff = df_pr.merge(df_ua, how="outer", indicator=True).loc[lambda x: x["_merge"] == "left_only"].drop("_merge", axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
ua_dic={}
with open('ua.csv') as ua:
  data=csv.reader(ua,delimiter=',')

  for i in data:
    if str(i) not in ua_dic:
        ua_dic[str(i)]=1

output=[]
with open('pr.csv') as pr:
  data=csv.reader(pr,delimiter=',')

  for j in data:
    if str(j) not in ua_dic:
        output.append(j)

  print(output)
```